# Can't Get RStudio Server to Run on EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I need to create an AMI with a clean install of `R` and `RStudio Server`. I have tried this on `Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)`, `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)`, and `Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM)` but none of them work. I do not get any errors (that I notice) in my installs but when I try to access `RStudio Server` via http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8787 there's nothing to connect to. I have even tried opening all ports to all IPs to make sure it wasn't a networking issue.

My Amazon API install scripts are below

**Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)**

```
sudo yum install -y R
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install -y rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
rm rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
```

**Amazon Linux 2 AMI**

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y R3.4
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install -y rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
rm rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.1335-x86_64.rpm
```

I get this as part of the result:

```
Running transaction
Installing : rstudio-server-1.0.153-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1/1 
groupadd: group 'rstudio-server' already exists
rsession: no process found
rstudio-server start/running, process 4990
  Verifying  : rstudio-server-1.0.153-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1/1 

Installed:
  rstudio-server.x86_64 0:1.0.153-1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

Complete!
```

I think the issue is the `rsession: no process found` portion but I can't figure out how to resolve it.